# PHP: set @deprecated annotation for annotated @method

Tags: php, annotations, phpdoc

I can set `@deprecated` annotation for PHP method:

```
/**
 * @deprecated 
 */
public function deprecatedMethod()
{

}
```

How can I mark annotated `@method` as deprecated?

```
/**
 * @method deprecatedMethod() 
 */
class Foo {...}
```

Comment: Is `deprecatedMethod()` a magic method or why are you using the `@method` tag?

Comment: Class `Foo` has a magic method (`__call`, for example) and annotated `deprecatedMethod` was an actual before and is deprecated now. I have an IDE hints for annotated methods and deprecated methods (normally defined). I wish to have a hints for deprecated annotated methods.

Comment: I see. According to [this issue](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1604) deprecated magic methods are currently not possible in phpDocumentor. I don't know about your IDE though.